# window.open(pdffile) generates 404 the requested resource is not available error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am downloading file from server which is dynamically generated. I am using `window.open()` function for opening url. I am facing problem. I want to know that whether the file is successfully opened or not. I am using

```
window.open(url, name, "width=910,height=750,scrollbars=yes");
```

for opening file but it always opening a window. I want to check whether file is successfully opened or not.

Comment: What has this got to do with Java?  Note that `Java!=JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on the title, it sounds like you're running into what's called a 404 error, or in common English "File Not Found". That means that the path you are supplying to the *.pdf file you want to open is incorrect, ie you're asking the system to open a pdf that doesn't exist.

Since the first argument in `window.open()` is the Path to the pdf file, look at that variable and fix where it's wrong.